# Im just confused when we should use new key in c++?

Tags: c++, qt

I'm new to c++ and I am trying to create simple menubar in Qt using QAction and QMenu and when I use new to create QAction object, it works and I see that item in menubar but when I try to create an object without using a new key although it runs without issue that item does not appear in menubar. I just want to know why this happens.

```
  QMenu* _fileMenu=menuBar()->addMenu("&File");
    QAction* _openAction=new QAction("&Open",this);
    QAction* _saveAction=new QAction("&Save",this);
    QAction helpAction("&Help",this);
    QAction* helpPointer=&helpAction;
   
    _fileMenu->addAction(_openAction);//works fine
    _fileMenu->addAction(_saveAction);//works fine
    _fileMenu->addAction(helpPointer);//Doesnt show any changes
```

Comment: The usage of `new` in your case has everything to do with the Qt framework you're using.   If the Qt documentation states you must use `new`, then you must use `new`.  Otherwise, without any frameworks, when you use `new`, you must use `delete` to deallocate the memory.

Comment: In Qt the QObject class has a parent / child deletion model where when a parent object is deleted it automatically frees its children. Related: [https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#dtor.QObject](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#dtor.QObject)

Comment: `QAction* helpPointer=&helpAction;` Make sure that you don't do this in any function other than `int main()` the reason is `helpAction`  will have its lifetime end at the end of the current scope.

Comment: It will be valid in the current scope but when the scope ends it no longer exists. So while the 2 other actions will still exist the `helpAction` is no more. You are calling this code in some function which is a member of some class. The scope will end when the function finishes its execution.

Comment: i think i got it and thanks ,so using new key is the only way we can create objects like this in qt if  i am not wrong,but when should we delete that pointers creates with new ,and is it needed at all.  @drescherjm

Comment: @mohammadfarjamy -- Read the second comment.  All of those details are handled by the Qt framework.

Comment: You can make these `QAction` variables members of your class if you don't want to use new. With that said since Qt manages the deletion for you the concern about memory leaks is reduced as long as you make sure to set the parent pointer.

Answer (score 0):

Because you create `helpAction` on the stack and it gets destroyed immediately after you leave the scope of the function in which you created it. So it is temporarily added to the meny via `helpPointer` but then, just when the functions ends, it is destroyed and hence removed from the menu. So the final result of the function is that `helpAction` is NOT PRESENT in the menu because it DOES NOT EXIST at all when the function is finished.

If you want to have it in the menu, you have to allocate it dynamically. Which is typically done with keyword `new`.